# Flutter Riverpod : Problems fetching data from Firebase using Riverpod

Tags: firebase, flutter, listview, riverpod

I'm changing from Getx to Riverpod.
So, Problems fetching data from Firebase using Riverpod.

I have two product data on the server.
Initially after running, the ProductListPage doesn't show anything.
Enter the page again and the list will be displayed.
And every time you enter, the list is piled up.
How to fetch data from server using Riverpod?

**Model**

```
  class Product {
  String id;
  String name;
  String category;
  String image;
  String images;
  String desc;
  String price;
  Timestamp createdAt;
  Timestamp updatedAt;

  Product();

  Product.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> data) {
    id = data['id'] ?? "ID Data Null";
    name = data['name'] ?? "Name Data Null";
    category = data['category'] ?? "Category Data Null";
    image = data['image'] ?? "Image Data Null";
    //images = data['images'];
    desc = data['desc'] ?? "Desc Data Null";
    price = data['price'] ?? "Price Data Null";
    createdAt = data['createdAt'];
    updatedAt = data['updatedAt'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'id': id,
      'name': name,
      'category': category,
      'images': images,
      'image': image,
      'desc': desc,
      'price': price,
      'createdAt': createdAt,
      'updatedAt': updatedAt
    };
  }
}
```

**Riverpod Provider**

```
 final productListProvider = StateNotifierProvider<ProductList>((ref) {
   return ProductList();
});


class ProductList extends StateNotifier<List<Product>> {
  //static Product productModel = Product();
  ProductList([List<Product> state]) : super(state ?? []);

  productAdd(Product product) {
    state.add(product);
  }

  Future<void> refreshList() async {
    getStateProducts();
  }

  getStateProducts() async {
    QuerySnapshot snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('Products')
        .get();
   
    snapshot.docs.forEach((document) {
   
      Product _product = Product.fromMap(document.data());
      productAdd(_product);
      print('DataBase: ${_product.name}');
    });
  }
```

**ProductPage ListView**

```
  class ProductListPage extends ConsumerWidget {
  

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, ScopedReader watch) {
    
    final productObj = watch(productListProvider);
    final product = watch(productListProvider.state);

    productObj.getStateProducts(); //

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Product List'),
      ),
      body: new RefreshIndicator(
          child: ListView.separated(
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return ListTile(
                leading: Image.network(
                  product[index].image != null
                      ? product[index].image
                      : 'https://www.testingxperts.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/placeholder-img.jpg',
                  width: 120,
                  fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                ),
                title: Text(product[index].name),
                subtitle: Text(product[index].category),
                onTap: () {
                  // getxController.currentIndex(index);
                  // getxController.currentProduct =
                  // getxController.productList[index];
                  // return Get.to(ProductDetail(), arguments: "test");
                },
              );
            },
            itemCount: product.length,
            separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
              return Divider(
                color: Colors.black,
              );
            },
          ),
          onRefresh: productObj.refreshList), // Refresh 
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/all.dart';

List<Product> productList = [
  Product(category: "categoryA", id: "0010", name: "ProductA"),
  Product(category: "categoryB", id: "0010", name: "ProductB"),
  Product(category: "categoryC", id: "0011", name: "ProductC"),
  Product(category: "categoryD", id: "0011", name: "ProductD"),
];

final productListStateProvider =
    StateNotifierProvider((ref) => ProductListState());

class ProductListState extends StateNotifier<AsyncValue<List<Product>>> {
  ProductListState([AsyncValue<List<Product>> state])
      : super(state ?? AsyncValue.data(<Product>[]));

  Future<List<Product>> getStateProducts() async {
    state = AsyncValue.loading();
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));
    final result = productList;
    state = AsyncValue.data(productList);
    return result;
  }
}

class ProductsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ProductsPageState createState() => _ProductsPageState();
}

class _ProductsPageState extends State<ProductsPage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    context.read(productListStateProvider).getStateProducts();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Stackoverflow answer"),
      ),
      body: Container(
       child: RefreshIndicator(
            onRefresh: () => 
         context.read(productListStateProvider).getStateProducts(),
      child: ProductListWidget()
      ),
  ),
    );
  }
}

class ProductListWidget extends ConsumerWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, ScopedReader watch) {
    final resultData = watch(productListStateProvider.state);
    return resultData.maybeWhen(
        data: (results) => ListView.builder(
            itemCount: results.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              final product = results[index];
              return ListTile(
                title: Text(product.name),
                subtitle: Text(product.category),
              );
            }),
        loading: () => Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
        error: (er, st) => Center(child: Text("Error occurred")), 
        orElse: () => Text("No data yet"));
  }
}

@immutable
class Product {
  final String id;
  final String name;
  final String category;
  final String image;
  final String images;
  final String desc;
  final String price;
  final dynamic createdAt;
  final dynamic updatedAt;

  Product({
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.category,
    this.image,
    this.images,
    this.desc,
    this.price,
    this.createdAt,
    this.updatedAt,
  });
}
```

Comment: Has been improved. However, the product.length is '0' and the list is still not displayed on the screen. It looks like you need some other logic. Thank you.

Comment: checkout the edited answer above maybe it could help you. No need for the add function though, if the productlist page is just pulling all the products from firebase

Comment: I tested it with your suggestion and it helped me solve the problem. Also, the first suggestion 'autoDispose' was useful. However, I am not sure if this is the correct way to use Riverpod. Also, onRefresh doesn't work. We are working more on this.Thank you.

Comment: are you talking about my answer? cos i ran it before putting it up here and its working

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tested it regarding your suggestion, and it worked out successfully. It helps me a lot.

Comment: you can also check medium story about fetching data with riverpod

https://aidooyaw1992.medium.com/make-an-api-call-with-riverpod-and-freezed-package-ab17c631641d

Comment: Im having a problem that im trying to solve, is there any way this could be fixed with river pod, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70980002/flutter-use-variable-created-inside-future-builder-outside-of-the-build-method?noredirect=1#comment125492412_70980002